# Windows10 - Explorer crashes on Application launch

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

My explorer crashes if I start an application. A second later it restarts. So if I try to open taskmgr it crashes and taskmgr doesn't start. But I can run commands via path box (where you can see the path of the current folder). But I can't run anything there as admin. But I can run these "Metro Apps" 
What I already did:

- Reset my PC without erasing my data
- Fully reset my PC with a backup on my external hdd

In the setup of my system I used my same Microsoft Account. 
But the problem is there again.

//Update 
I see that my command line also doesnt start anything. And in the PC Settings (Windows 10 Settings) crashes if I try to create a new local account
Ctrl + Alt + Del then TaskManager and Ctrl + Shift + Esc dont work

//UPDATE 2
Via tasklist /FI "STATUS eq UNKNOWN" I see all programs I tried to start until now

Comment: Any application or a specific application?

Comment: All applications except of the Metro apps (MS Edge, Shop and so on)

Comment: I see that my command line also doesnt start anything. And in the PC Settings (Windows 10 Settings) crashes if I try to create a new local account

Comment: You should update your question with additional information.

Comment: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/process-explorer/ download this software and watch your explorer. see what happens. what triggers the error. also go into your event view and check errors.

Comment: I already downloaded it xD and I can't open the event viewer of windows :/

Comment: As far as I see the process I try to start gets suspended and the Explorer restarts and the Windows Error Logger (WerFault) starts with these arguments:  -u -p 3140 -s 7904

Comment: I am sure some uninformed person will claim I am wrong but `Ctrl + Alt + Del` cannot be disabled.  You can configure what is shown when that shortcut is used but it cannot be disabled.  So if it isn't working then you have severe system integrity issues which merit you simply reinstall Windows which can only be done if you are authorized to do so.  Since you are not an Administrator you shouldn't be trying to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: No I am Adminitstrator and I reinstalled Windows already.

Comment: I have no ideas anymore... I did sfc /scannow via utilman cmd replacement but after a restart nothing changed except of that replacement. What can I do?

Comment: capture a crash dump of the crashing Explorer: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU and share the compressed (7z/RAR) dmp file

Comment: have you captured the crash dump?

Comment: and now the issue is gone?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yep I think if I would have used the feature of windows it wouldn't help at all. Because Windows doesn't reset everything (my theory)

Comment: ok, post an answer of hat you have done and mark it as answer

Comment: No wait. I'll do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like file corruption. Follow these recommendations. If you have difficulties using these tools try boot machine in safe mode.

I would check your HD to ensure there are no bad blocks.

1. Open a command prompt
2. type `chkdsk c: /f /r`
3. Answer yes at the prompt to schedule scan at next boot.
4. Reboot machine at let it perform scan

[Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833)

1. Start a Command Prompt
2. Type `sfc /scannow`

Comment: I can't run it I need administrator but if I try to run anything as admin it crashes. Is it possible via windows repair / install disk

Comment: @Scrumplex - If you are not an administrator on this machine this cannot be solved.  You need to get an your local network administrator to help you.

Comment: I am in the Administrator Group but I cant elevate anything to admin. If I try the program I try to elevate crashes. (Process state gets suspended)

Comment: So now I'm doing the chkdsk via Repair Disk. After that I will try sfc.

Comment: Have you tried safe mode? http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10

Comment: Yes I tried safe mode I cant do anything there too. CHKDSK didn't find any errors after some hours. And SFC throws an error